# jQuery find() by classname syntax comparison

Tags: jquery

Aren't the following function calls "exactly same"

```
$(document).find(".classname") //does not work
$(document).find(" .classname") //note the extra space, works fine
$(document).find("[class='classname']") //works fine
```

For some reason, the first function call does not return any element while other two function calls works fine.

If I change first function call to

```
$(document).find("div.classname") //works fine 
or $(document).find('html').find(".classname") //works fine
```

it works fine.

I am confused why the first function call does not work

Comment: are you sure the element exist?can you check length?

Comment: @guradio I am testing on same html only inside chrome. In console window, the other two calls works while first one does not. So, if element is missing, the other two won't work also

Comment: which version of jQuery? with Version 1.11.1 it works. I just tested it.

Comment: The problem is not the selector because ***$(document).find(".classname")*** is correct and will work if there is such element ***and*** the html-document is valid for javascript to work on. I suspect that you have an error or errors in your html.

Comment: can you post the html code that doesn't work. (the minimal needed)